# TailwindCSS - Set all grid items to be the same height

Tags: html, css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I wanted to create grid with Tailwind CSS where all items have the same height.

But when children have different content length, their background color is not filling whole cell:

[image: screenshot]

---

Grid markup:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 auto-rows-max">{ITEMS}</div>
```

Item markup:

```html
<div class="rounded-md overflow-hidden ring-1 ring-blue-600 ring-opacity-20">
  <div class="bg-red-200 p-6 flex flex-col justify-between ">{BODY}</div>
</div>
```

I thought that `auto-rows-max` was the solution but it's not working.

Interactive example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/dlgGmz41dA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying the background color one tag too late. Just move `bg-red-200` up to the div with `rounded-md overflow-hidden...` and each grid cell will have full color backgrounds regardless of content length.

Item markup:

```
<div class="bg-red-200 rounded-md overflow-hidden ring-1 ring-blue-600 ring-opacity-20">
  <div class="p-6 flex flex-col justify-between ">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/Lf7nF97Be1